# Trouble with virtual SDCard

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to download a database from a link, but when I create a `FileOutputstream` object, it promts an `FileNotFoundException`, telling me that the acces is denied. I investigated a little and found it could be the sdcard, when I used  `Environment.getExternalStorageState()`   to see what was happening, it tells me the sd card is removed. I checked and saw that the sd is correctly inserted into the virtual device, so how could I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I already have the permission on the manifest to wite on external device.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in your manifest?

Comment: Yes I forgot to add that, but I have that permission already.

Comment: A FileNotFoundException telling me that I have an acces denied.